# How can I refresh one dataset in dataprep?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, etl, google-cloud-dataprep

I have one flow in Dataprep that uses one table in Bigquery, the schema of that table has changed, now how can I refresh the initial import without affect my ETLs or delete my steps.

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding that the nature of the BQ connector works in a way where, every time your flow is processed, be that opening a recipe, stepping in a recipe, running a job ... GDP always checks the data source. If the source data has changed, your results in GDP will change.

Someone please enlighten me if I'm wrong.

Best.

/e